# C++ derived-class members after downcasting

Tags: c++, casting, dynamic-cast, downcast, upcasting

I recently learned about upcasting and downcasting in C++. However I came up with a few questions during reading about downcasting. Say I have two classes

```
class Base {
  public:
    virtual void foo() {}
};

class Derived : public Base {
  public:
    Derived(int i) {
        mem = i;
    }
    int mem;
};
```

My questions are the followings:

1. If I create an object `Derived d(1)`, upcast to Base class, and then downcast it back to Derived class, is 'mem==1' preserved? Do I still have access to it? Assume pointer or reference is used so object slicing doesn't happen and dynamic_cast is used for downcasting.
2. When downcasting from Base class to Derived class, there will an additional member variable 'mem'. Is memory allocated for 'mem' during run-time (using dynamic_cast)? To what value will it be initialized to?

After some simple experiments, 1 seems to be true.

However for 2 it seems I can't start from a Base class pointer and dynamic_cast it into Derived class pointer as dynamic_cast returns null.

I read from another post saying "**But the basic point of dynamic_cast is that it first checks that the pointee object is really of the derived type, and then returns a pointer to it, or returns a null pointer if the pointee object isn't actually of (or derived from) the requested target type.**"

Is this saying we can't actually start from the Base class and simply downcast it into Derived class, but rather the whole point of dynamic_cast is to "cast back" something that has been upcasted?

Comment: Do you check that the dynamic_cast succeeds? If the dynamic cast fails and you just attempt to dereference a `nullptr`, that's undefined behavior and anything goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It depends; if you cast a `Derived` **object** to `Base`, the result is a new object created by omitting the fields that are not in the `Base`. However, if you cast a **pointer** to `Derived` (i.e. `Derived*`), the result is a pointer which points to the same object but whose type is `Base*`.
2. It depends; if you cast a `Base` **object**, you get a compile error unless you [overload the typecast operator](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/overloading-typecasts/) for doing such an operation (you have correctly observed that the values of the fields would otherwise be undefined). However, if you cast a `Base*` (a **pointer**) to `Derived*` (using `dynamic_cast<Derived*>(p)`), the result depends on the object the pointer points to. If it points to an instance of the `Derived` class (or its subclass), the result is a `Derived*` pointer to that object; otherwise, you get a `nullptr` pointer of type `Derived*`.

Comment: Thanks! So in the case of doing `Base* b = new Derived(10)` and then `Derived* d = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(b)`, I'll get back a non-nullptr right? Assuming there's no other problem

Comment: @jleng Yes, exactly.